# Pass url value from background image style property

Tags: javascript, html, properties, styles, queryselector

I have html code below:

```
<li class="name1 name2 name3" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" style="background-image: url(images/gallery-1.jpg); ">
```

Then how to set `images/gallery-1.jpg` to my `imageURL` variable javascript by querySelector? This is my try and error:

```
let imageURL = gallery[newIndex].querySelector("li").style.background.url;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more code needed

You can change `document.querySelector("[data-animate-effect]")` to `gallery[newIndex].querySelector("li")` if preferred

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("[data-animate-effect]")
  .style.backgroundImage.match(/"(.*)"/)[1])
```

```html
<li class="name1 name2 name3" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" style="background-image: url(images/gallery-1.jpg); ">
```

Comment: thanks the url value shown on my console

Answer (score 0):

Select the item, get the [computed style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), and retrieve the background image information. Then extract the URL from that data with a regular expression, and [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match).

```js
const li = document.querySelector('li');
const style = window.getComputedStyle(li);
const imageUrl = style.getPropertyValue('background-image');
console.log(imageUrl.match(/"(.+)"/)[1]);
```

```html
<li class="name1 name2 name3" data-animate-effect="fadeIn" style="background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/100x100/666/ff0'); ">
```

Answer (score -2):

Use .replace() to regular expressions when possible, since it's often easier to read:

javascript code

```
var image = $("li").css("background-image")
image = image.replace(/.*\s?url\([\'\"]?/, '').replace(/[\'\"]?\).*/, '')
```

Output:

```
images/gallery-1.jpg
```

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery.